# How do I use MacOS keyboard layout on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: keyboard-layout, macos

In addition to using Ubuntu 20.04, I have recently started doing some of my work on MacOS. The problem, however, is that my typing speed on both is not so good. On the one hand, the MacOS keyboard layout is new for me, so there isn't much muscular memory to work with. On the other hand, remapping my finger gestures to the MacOS keyboard layout is interfering with my typing on Ubuntu.

I currently prefer the MacOS keyboard layout, so I would like to just use the same keyboard layout on my Ubuntu machine. Is there a way to implement the whole MacOS keyboard layout in Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By far the easiest solution for this is installing Kinto that is made for exactly this: https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto#how-to-install-linux

It not only remaps the Ubuntu keyboard layout to match the MacOS shortcuts, it also lets you use for example CMD-V for paste, like on the Mac in the Ubuntu Terminal and more. (By default you need to type SUPER-SHIFT-V in Ubuntu terminal to paste...).